# Can Apache OfBiz be installed with an existing version of Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, ofbiz

I installed Tomcat last year with mod_jk for Dashbuilder.  I'd like to install OfBiz which also uses Tomcat but it appears that Tomcat is included in the OfBiz files.

How can I run Tomcat with mod_jk for a reverse proxy and multiple applications such as OfBiz and Dashbuilder?

Configurations:

apache conf file

```
JkMount /dashbuilder* worker1
JkMount /someapp2r* worker2
JkMount /someapp3* worker3
JkMount /ofbiz* worker4
```

workers.properties

```
worker.list=worker1, worker2, worker3, worker4,status
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=127.0.0.1
worker.worker1.port=8009

worker.list=worker2
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.host=127.0.0.1
worker.worker2.port=8009

worker.list=worker3
worker.worker3.type=ajp13
worker.worker3.host=127.0.0.1
worker.worker3.port=8009

worker.list=worker4
worker.worker3.type=ajp13
worker.worker3.host=127.0.0.1
worker.worker3.port=8009

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

Error With an existing Tomcat 8.5 running with mod_jk for other applications

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 22, 2018 10:51:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Error after turning off the exiting version of Tomcat 8.5 and tried to run ofbiz.

```
INFO: No global web.xml found
```

I searched for worker and found this but it might or might not be relevant.

```
runtime/logs/ofbiz-2018-10-22-1.log:3218:2018-10-22 02:59:49,428 |kJoinPool-1-worker-1 |ModelServiceReader            |W| Service deleteWorkEffortInventoryProduced is defined more than once, most recent will over-write previous definition(s)
```

grep -rsn kJoinPool *

```
framework/base/src/main/java/org/apache/ofbiz/base/concurrent/ExecutionPool.java:45:    public static final ForkJoinPool GLOBAL_FORK_JOIN = new ForkJoinPool();
```

grep -rsn GLOBAL_FORK_JOIN *

```
framework/base/src/main/java/org/apache/ofbiz/base/concurrent/ExecutionPool.java:45:    public static final ForkJoinPool GLOBAL_FORK_JOIN = new ForkJoinPool();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using external Tomcat is no longer supported OOTB since R9.04. Please refer following [thread](https://markmail.org/message/hmhjygfpqqght233).

You can also use Apache OFBiz user mailing [list](https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) for such queries.

HTH